# How to show only the domain url even when calling google storage url

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have hosted my application on Google Compute VM. However, I have my static files like html stored on google storage. When I call the storage url, it shows something like `https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/index.html`. How can I make sure that only my domain is visible instead of the storage urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a [Domain-Named bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification) which will require verification of ownership from Google and if you have only a static website you could serve the whole website from Google Cloud Storage as advised on the [relevant section of the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

Comment: No. Its not a static site. When i hit the domain name , the request is servered from the load balancer which redirects the request to the login html on storage. The login then calls backed for authentication. In this case can i rename my bucket name with the domain name like `www.example.com`. Can it be the same name as my actual domain

Comment: Find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#gsutil) the instructions to move or rename your bucket. Use the [first link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification) on my answer to give it a domain name.

Comment: Even after I rename my bucket to my domain name. It still shows a url like `https://storage.gogoleapis.com/www.<domainname>.com/index.html`. How can I get access via just `www.<domainname>.com`

Comment: Sorry. I seemed to have misinterpreted your question. There should be a final step regarding the CNAME redirect as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#cname) (notice that it'll only work with HTTP). I was also able to find the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586721/generate-custom-urls-for-google-cloud-storage-buckets-object-using-api) from the community that you could also find interesting (haven't tested it though).

Comment: Oh yeah this is more what i was looking for though it seems a little overkill. Strange that google didn’t provide any default implementation for this